# Passing RDD through a function

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

Basically, I want to take data that I loaded as textFile that contains GPS coordinates on separate lines to input them as argument to a function to return a certain value. I'm stuck at passing the RDD as the argument. I understand the transformation and actions concept, but I cant wrap my head around how to pass as function and get the latitude and longitude to pass as an argument..

```
def tester(coord):
    ## Normally if i was iterating for the coming line
    panoids = streetview.panoids(lat=coord[i][0], lon=coord[i][1])
    ## append the output "panoids[0]['panoid']" to the original rdd as a third element

text_file = sc.textFile("filepath")
split_data = text_file.map(lambda line:line.split(','))
print split_data.take(2) ## [[u'47.642027', u'-2.755305'], [u'47.642124', u'-2.755161']]

output = tester(split_data)
print output.take(2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you can't modify a RDD per se. What you'd have to do is create a new RDD using the current information you have.

Here's the (untested) code to do something like that:

```
def tester(coord_row):
    panoids = streetview.panoids(lat=coord_row[0], lon=coord_row[1])
    return [coord_row[0], coord_row[1], panoids[0]['panoid']]

output = split_data.map(tester)
```

You take the current RDD and map each row into a new row which has the first columns as the same except there's an added element (panoid) in the RDD.

Comment: Typo in code: you should use `coord_row` inside `tester` function, not `coord`. However that's what I've suggested in my answer, so I totally agree with your solution :)

Comment: Thanks for noticing :) Fixed it now

Comment: worked perfectly, I didnt know I didnt have to point out somehow to iterate !

Answer (score 1):

It don't know Python, but code in pseudocode:

```
def tester (coords : RDD) = {
    coords.map (lambda c : {
    panoids = streetview.panoids(lat=c[0], lon=c[1])
    result = appendToArray (c, panoids)
    });
}
```

AppendToArray must create new array of 3 elements. I don't know how to do multi-line lambda in Python, but pseudocode should also be helpful :)

Explanation: You should not do it in iterative way, but functional. map() function will create new RDD in which every element is an element from old RDD transformed to new object. At the beggining you've got RDD of 2-dimensional array, you must in map() get value of 3rd dimension and append result to input array.